# android retrofit 2 post to laravel not working

Tags: java, php, android, laravel, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2, trying to send data to my laravel web.

InitRetrofit.java

```
public class InitRetrofit {
    public static String API_URL = "http://192.168.1.2/sra-copy/public/";
    public static Retrofit setInit(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }

    public static ApiService getInstance(){
        return setInit().create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

ApiService.java

```
public interface ApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("lapor/android")
    Call<ResponseLapor> input(@Field("lat") String lat,
                              @Field("lng") String lng,
                              @Field("jenis") String jns,
                              @Field("keterangan") String ket);
}
```

response class ResponseLapor.java

```
public class ResponseLapor {
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

call retrofit

```
public void lapor(){
    lat = etLat.getText().toString();
    lng = etLng.getText().toString();
    keterangan = etKet.getText().toString();
    jns = "Ringan";

    ApiService api = InitRetrofit.getInstance();

    retrofit2.Call<ResponseLapor> call = api.input(lat, lng, jns, keterangan);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseLapor>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<ResponseLapor> call, Response<ResponseLapor> response) {
            String message = response.body().getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(Lapor.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<ResponseLapor> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(Lapor.this, "Jaringan Error! "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

route

```
Route::post('lapor/android', 'AndroidController@Lapor')->name('android.lapor');
```

controller

```
public function Lapor(Request $request){
    // dd($request->all());
    $msg = array();
    if($request->jenis == "Ringan"){
        $rs = RumahSakit::select(DB::raw('*, ( 6367 * acos( cos( radians('.$request->lat.') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('.$request->lng.') ) + sin( radians('.$request->lat.') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance'))->having('distance', '<', 25)->orderBy('distance')->get();
        DB::table('status')->insert([
            'nama_sts' => $rs->first()->nama_rs,
            'keterangan' => $request->keterangan,
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ]);

        $msg["message"] = $rs->first()->nama_rs;
    }
    else{
        $msg["message"] = "Error Jenis Laporan";
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

The controller works when tried to insert from web.
When I send the data the first time, it doesn't show any toast, then the second time I get this error:

```
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.String com.example.sra.response.ResponseLapor.getMessage()' on a null object reference
```

I think that the error has to do with the URL because I have another android project using the same structure and it is successfully inserting data to localhost (not laravel) just native PHP.

Comment: how you serve your laravel become a web server? xampp, iis, or php artisan serve?

Comment: @Kelvin tried using both localhost (with url in the code) and ip from php artisan serve, both not still not working

Comment: if i used http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (php artisan serve) it says failed to connect

Comment: if you are using php artisan serve, it would be serve in local with port 8000, and you need to allow firewall on port 8000 on that local ip address so other LAN can use the port. Then access the ip address http://192.168.1.2:8000/

Comment: also make sure you access the ip with the port before compile your program, simple way to check using cmd ping 192.168.1.2:8000

Comment: @Kelvin tried to ping 192.168.1.2:8000 and 127.0.0.1:8000 both says could not find the host, already activated php artisan serve, and allowed firewall on port 8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** 
i finally figured it out from trying to post using Postman it gives error 419 Page Expired, because it doesn't have csrf token (because i posted it directly to the controller without view that i can added csrf to),
 so i added exception of the url on VerifyCsrfToken.php in middleware folder so it became like this

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        //
        '/lapor/android'
    ];
}
```

maybe there are another way to do it, like generating csrf token inside the controller.
hope this will help somebody.